# For the Destruction by Ki ability, do structures/inanimate objects roll for resistance?

Tags: anima-beyond-fantasy

For example, if a level 3 character uses the ability **Destruction by Ki** against lets say a "Solid Bridge" (PhR 80) and spends 1 ki to perform the attack, plus 1 extra ki to raise the difficulty of the check to a total of 45 (character base presence 40 + 5), will the bridge be destryed? as its total PhR is 80, meaning it does not "pass their resistance check by 40 or more".

Or does the bridge get to roll a D100 and add the result (for an average of 130)?

I cannot find any instances where an inanimate object would get to roll a dice, but this would get broken quickly, as a level 6 character (55 presence) pumping in 10 extra ki (+50) would raise the check to 105, meaning a level 6 character can destroy a "Town" (PhR 140) with a single touch by spending 11 ki,as it cannot pass the check by 40 or more points.

#### Destruction by Ki (Corebook page 96)

> ...forces a targeted body to pass a Physical Resistance Check against the base Presence of the character using this ability.
> ... unless inorganic objects pass their resistance check by 40 or more, they are immediately destroyed ...

#### Presence (Corebook page 217-218)

> Since inanimate objects have no characteristics, their resistances (basically PhR and MR) are equal to their base presence